# Ansible - establishing initial SSH connection

Tags: ssh, ansible

I am trying to copy an SSH public key to a newly created VM:

```
- hosts: vm1
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
    - name: deploy ssh key to account
      authorized_key: user='root' key="{{lookup('file','/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub')}}"
```

But getting error:

> fatal: [jenkins]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).\r\n", "unreachable": true}

So to establish SSH I need first to establish SSH?

How can I establish SSH for newly created KVM automatically, without manual key copy.

(`host_key_checking = False` in `ancible.cfg`)

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the target machine allows root-login with password (from the error message it seems it does), you must provide the credentials to your playbook:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml --extra-vars "ansible_ssh_user=root ansible_ssh_pass=password"
```

Comment: Alternatively, if you run the playbook with the -k option, ansible will prompt you for the ssh password.

Comment: I used the following command to manually input my username and password for amiable to login -> `ansible-playbook server.yml -e env=production -u root --ask-pass`

Answer (score 4):

Something I tried (and it worked) when I had this same issue:

```
ansible target-server-name -m command -a "whatever command" -k
```

The **`-k`** prompts you for the ssh password to the target server.

Add below changes to the */etc/ansible/hosts* file:

```
[target-server-name]
target_server_ip
```

Example:

```
ansible target-server-name -m ping -k
```